# Can anyone help install abuntu onsamsung chromebook 3 xe303c12 having update issues. Wont let me finish crout setup

Tags: command-line, software-installation, chromebook, crouton

I have a samsung chromebook 3 xe303c12 model I've already turned to developer mode on and installed a fresh crouton installer, when I tried installing thru alt-control-T command page = I used Shell to prep then used the command ' sudo install - Dt /usr/local/bin -m 755 ~/Downloads/crouton
Then I used command sudo crouton - t xfce to start download of latest crouton installer, everything went as planned until I get an
Error saying "Failed to fetch http://ports.ubuntu.com/ubuntu-ports/pool/main/d/dpkg/dpkg_1.18.44ubuntu1.7_armhf.deb Hash sum mismatch. Can some one help me with finishing the installation?

Comment: You've not provided any OS/release details; but the oldest supported `dpkg` for this site is `dpkg | 1.19.0.5ubuntu2   | bionic          | source, amd64, arm64, armhf, i386, ppc64el, s390x`  where your message shows an older & thus off-topic release for this site, even if you're using a on-topic Ubuntu OS.

Comment: [Ubuntu 16.04 LTS has reached the end of it's *standard* support life](https://fridge.ubuntu.com/2021/03/13/extended-security-maintenance-for-ubuntu-16-04-xenial-xerus-begins-april-30-2021/) thus is now off-topic here unless your question is specific to helping you move to a supported release of Ubuntu.  Ubuntu 16.04 ESM support is available, but not on-topic here, see https://askubuntu.com/help/on-topic  See also https://ubuntu.com/blog/ubuntu-16-04-lts-transitions-to-extended-security-maintenance-esm   *You maybe using another release but this is close to what your package looks like*

Comment: Note:  your package doesn't match what I saw in my prior comment; which is the reason for your error (*I didn't paste what I saw as it's ESM*), but you didn't provide release details that are needed to help, but even if you had, you're off-topic here due to EOL

Comment: Yess you are correcto I am running that versión but it seems I got passed that hick-up but now it wont start the crouton with sudo xfce4., shows error running 1.19.6 xenial versión. Any tips I know this is out of date but trying to get atleast some usability from this chromebook. Or would anyone suggest a better solusion or program to run to extendí its life. Seem crouton - r trusty - t lxde is ay the end of its life and no longer receiving updates.

Answer (score 1):

You're trying to run a Ubuntu 16.04 chroot, which is what Crouton provides by default if I'm understanding correctly. That's probably your problem.

Run `crouton -r list` to see the list of recognized releases, and if 18.04 or newer is in there, something like `sudo crouton -r <insert the code for Ubuntu 18.04 or newer here> -t xfce` should probably let you install a supported version of Ubuntu.

Note that I say "something like" and "probably" in here. That's because *I've never used Crouton before and have no idea how to use it beyond the instructions at https://github.com/dnschneid/crouton/blob/master/README.md.* So if this doesn't work at all, I'm sorry, you'll have to do a bit more digging. But based off of the section "Hey now, Ubuntu 16.04 is pretty old; I'm young and hip" in the README linked above, I *think* this is how to do it.

Crouton is probably not going to be the best way to run Ubuntu on your Chromebook - it's no longer actively developed beyond minor changes like bug fixes, and it openly states that the way it lets you run Linux is messy and potentially won't work. What I would do is flash the firmware, chuck Chrome OS entirely, and install Ubuntu directly. The process is a bit of an ordeal, but the basic idea is:

1. [Make sure your device is compatible with MrChromebox firmware](https://mrchromebox.tech/#devices). You're looking for a checkbox for your device in the "UEFI Firmware (Full ROM)" column. If your device is supported, the rest of everything should work.
2. Download a supported Ubuntu flavor (I'd recommend Lubuntu 22.04), and flash it to a flash drive using `dd` on the Chromebook.
3. Figure out how to disable firmware write protect on your Chromebook - usually this is done by removing a particular screw from the motherboard (which involves taking the Chromebook apart). How exactly to do this will depend on your manufacturer and model of Chromebook - Google should help you find where the screw is.
4. Once you've disabled the firmware write protect, put everything back together, and then use the [MrChromebox Firmware Utility Script](https://mrchromebox.tech/#fwscript) to flash the firmware. **Make good and sure that you've made a bootable Ubuntu flash drive first - once you do this, Chrome OS will be rendered unbootable.**
5. Shut down the Chromebook, turn it back on, wait for it to try (and fail) to boot so that the firmware can initialize for the first time, then turn it back off again. Then you can plug in your Ubuntu flash drive and install Ubuntu like you'd install it on any other computer.

Please be careful if you choose to do this - if you make a mistake, you could kill the Chromebook entirely. (I've done at least four Chromebooks like this, and it worked out OK all four times, although one of them is a bit finicky powering on - I'm not sure if it's my fault or not, but hey, it works!) Also, this is not a full guide, but more of a rough idea - I left out potentially important steps like ISO verification and backing up your data. So do your research before you dive in. I'd **highly** recommend that you make sure you have a second computer before trying this, so that you're not stranded without any computer at all in the event this goes wrong.

Disclaimer: I am *not* affiliated in any way with MrChromebox. However, I am a Lubuntu Member, so while my recommendation that you use Lubuntu 22.04 is because it's lightweight, it's also because I like Lubuntu. :-) However, if you like the XFCE desktop, you can also use Xubuntu instead.